# What is the latest and greatest socket.io benchmark module currently?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to script benchmark of my socket.io implementation.

After some research I have identified several NodeJS modules, but they have either not been updated for past years (`wsbench`), or are only supporting websocket protocol (`wsbench`, `thor`) or is not testing socket.io implementation but socket.io project (`socket.io-benchmark`).

Since socket.io project has been highly active the past year, I wonder what is the latest and greatest tool/module to use for benchmarking?

My requirements:

- Easy to script and run the tests
- Test reports giving good overview of test runs
- Test reports should be easy to save in order to compare with later benchmarking

Comment: It seems like there is no clear answer on this. From what I have seen so far you basically need to code most of this by your self. Good starting point is the [socket.io-benchmark](https://github.com/michetti/socket.io-benchmark) project.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this in search of some benchmarking for my Socket.IO project.

I found socket.io-benchmark, however had some additional items that I wanted to work through but found one of the forks nearly there.

https://github.com/slowthinker/socket.io-benchmark

I also forked it to add a cap on messagse/second sent to give it more realistic parameters.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **Artillery**: Artillery is a modern, powerful, easy-to-use, open-source load-testing toolkit: https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery

Here some feature:

> - Mulitple protocols: Load-test HTTP, WebSocket and Socket.io applications
> - Scenarios: Specify scenarios to test multi-step interactions in your API or web app
> - Perfomance metrics: get detailed performance metrics (latency, requests per second, concurrency, throughput)
> - Scriptable: write custom logic in JS to do pretty much anything
> - High performance: generate serious load on modest hardware
> - Integrations: statsd support out of the box for real-time reporting (integrate with Datadog, Librato, InfluxDB etc)
> - Extensible: custom reporting plugins, custom protocol engines etc
>     and more! HTML reports, nice CLI, parameterization with CSV files